# Page Automatically Generated from Theme?

Tags: php, pages, page-template

I'm running WordPress multisite and would like each site to have a specific page (with pre-loaded content) generated from a page template, contact.php. Rather than go through each site and create this page, I would like it to be created automatically by the theme. I plan to add all the content in contact.php itself. I'm assuming there is a way I can do this with a theme hack but have no idea where to start.

To put it more simply, the theme would automatically create a page at domain.com/contact from the template contact.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `functions.php` file:

```
$contact_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'pagename' => 'contact',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
));
if (! $contact_query->post_count)
    wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_name' => 'contact',
        'post_title' => 'Contact',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'page_template' => 'page-contact.php',
    ));
unset($contact_query);
```

**What does it do?**
If the contact page does not exist, create it.

Comment: This generates the page multiple times. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Thank you. However, it seems this code isn't generating any pages (whereas the last code was generating the page multiple times over, indefinitely). Is there something I need to do to trigger the generation?

Comment: This new code is, once again, generating the page multiple times over and over. Thank you for your efforts on this thus far. I assume the first part of the code isn't recognizing the generated page for some reason but I am unable to find a solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please remove the above code from your `functions.php` file, then go to your WP Admin, delete **all** contact pages, then insert the code again, and all should be good.